# Send post with json string to server

Tags: c++, c, ios5, android-ndk

I want to write application which can run on android and ios both in C++. I need to communicate with server a lot. How to send post to server ? Is there class for this like HttpPost in Java ? I am very new to C++.

Comment: Why are you using c++ when android apps are written in Java, and iOS apps are written in objective-c?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libcURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to communicate with HTTP(s) servers.

**Edit**

I will also recommend [JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) for json handling, I found it easy and useful for simple tasks.